# How to "spread some words about" or "spread some word about"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Sorry for the dumb question.

If I have couple of sentences that describe my idea, should I use the first or the second phrase or neither of them ;)

Any insight and grammar references are very welcome!

**Context**

> My friends and I are doing this service. We use it every day and want
>   to spread some words about. I want to help you to understand the main
>   idea of the service and give an insight on how to start.

Comment: would it be possible to give a little more context to your sentences? The second one seems ungrammatical, but even the first one is not very clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using "spread the word around".

Comment: +1. I am sure this is what OP was looking for, even if he didn't know it.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't understand what you mean; however, if you are interested in letting people know about your service and how to use it, I'd say that you want ***to spread the word about*** or perhaps ***spread the news*** about your service.

Normally you shouldn't use "some" with a countable noun, and in your sentence it does not sound right even with a plural form.